# Link form correct, or, punishable by search engines?

Tags: seo, search-engines, url, links, keywords

I have the following dilemma with the links of a WordPress blog that I work with, I don't know if the way it creates the link to the images is ok or not so good.

For example:

- Article URL: `http://test.com/prima-de-riesgo/`
- Image URL belonging to the article: `http://test.com/prima-de-riesgo/europa/`

So what I'm worried about is the repeating "**prima-de-riesgo**" part. Should I, or shouldn't I?

### UPDATE

Wow, I can't believe that you took test.com as for the real domain, hehe!

- Article URL: `http://queaprendemoshoy.com/prima-de-riesgo-y-otras-graficas-interesantes-del-ano-2011-deuda-publica-pib-vs-empleo-y-precio-del-oro/`
- Image URL belonging to the article: `http://queaprendemoshoy.com/prima-de-riesgo-y-otras-graficas-interesantes-del-ano-2011-deuda-publica-pib-vs-empleo-y-precio-del-oro/deuda-publica-eurozona/`

So, as I mentioned... I'm worried that **prima-de-riesgo-y-otras-graficas-interesantes-del-ano-2011-deuda-publica-pib-vs-empleo-y-precio-del-oro** , the common factor for the article URL and image URL, can be considerate as duplicate content or anything that could be punishable by search engines

Comment: If you are not talking about the html code to insert the images, can you be more clear in your question?

Comment: check my question's update

Comment: Does the image have to load in a new page? Why not have it open in a modal window using prettyphoto pluing or one similar? Also if you install WordPress SEO by Yoast, you can remove the image pages from your sitemap and add meta noindex to those pages

Comment: General rule of thumb; If you're not malicious in your intent, Google won't punish you. So if you do A because your visitors find it easier, or it makes updating easier, or whatever the reason, as long as your'e not malicious, you should be fine. Since the URLs contain different content and is not copies of eachother, I don't see any reason why Google would punish you.

Answer (score 2):

I edited my answer to make it related to you update

No problem with your code, all the appearances of "prima-de-riesgo" seem to be in perfectly legal code, like cdata and href's, crawlers identify that as part of the url, and it's use is not punishable.

If the use where in hidden layers, background color, not connected text, links to the same page with no real purpose than to increase the link count or similar tactics, then yes, it will be a problem.

Comment: I'm not worried about the `img src` but the `a href`.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate content refers to having the same content (text, images, etc.) found at two (or more) different URLs. You shouldn't run into this problem, as 1) both links are distinctly different (the sub-folder the content is found within should not be a determining factor in  a search engine's crawler, as much as the end-point is, or there would be a LOT of sites that would have to use a different folder for each page in their site!), and 2) both links have distinctly different content.